# Custom Named PE Files and Headers

Tags: compiler-construction, static-analysis, portable-executable

I am going to start this question by stating i am a junior malware analyst, and am hoping someone who has been programming/analyzing headers can have some advice.

Generally when a compiler puts the .exe together, you will see the .text, .data., .rdata, .rsrc etc... but how could an author go about obscuring those names to confuse someone performing static analysis?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, these are just names of the sections and some packers like UPX changes these names to UPX0 or something else but these really don't matter since they are just names and you can change it to whatever you want. The important information in PE files include the address of these sections. You can read more about PE files in [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121209005010/http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/pe-tut1.html). It's a very nice tutorial about PE's structure. Also this one which gives you a better insight into PE files [here](https://blog.filovirid.com/page/Windows-Portable-Executable-Files-Structure).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, those names don't matter and can be anything. The loader looks at header and section flags and other data to understand how much memory is needed for the program, where (if there are no relocations), which parts need to be executable, which writable, which readable and so on. The loader takes care of that and does additional things like relocation and binding with DLLs. You can have just one section with most things in it, code, constant data, non-constant data, import info. For example, my compiler collects all data and import info under .data. At the moment there are a max of 3 different sections produced: .text, .data, .reloc (relocations are optional, btw) and Windows is happy.

Real obscuring should be done at a different level in compiled machine code, at what it does and how. E.g. use code as data and vice versa, use self-modified or generated at runtime code, use handcrafted code that would cause exceptions and divert execution into exception handlers, all those things that are hard to get right or follow if you're not actually executing the code (bonus points: different execution under a debugger). One can also insert quite a bit of code that essentially does nothing but is confusing and increases code complexity. One can also exploit bugs and limitations in analysis tools, e.g. do some unconventional things, use numbers that are too big and will cause overflows in calculations. And in the era of the Internet, the program may be incomplete and may download the missing parts from the Internet at runtime. Fun!

Answer (score 1):

The `dumpbin` visual studio utility can be used with the `/HEADERS` parameter to view all the section headers. Part of the output you might be interested in will look something like this:

```
SECTION HEADER #1  
   .text name  
    1000 virtual size  
    1000 virtual address (00401000 to 00401FFF)  
     200 size of raw data  
     200 file pointer to raw data (00000200 to 000003FF)  
       0 file pointer to relocation table  
       0 file pointer to line numbers  
       0 number of relocations  
       0 number of line numbers  
60000020 flags  
         Code  
         Execute Read
```

As you can see it gives the name as ".text" for the code section of this particular exe. This section can be renamed to anything as long as it conforms to the the [Microsoft specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx):

> For [names longer than 8 bytes], this field contains a slash (/) that is followed by an ASCII representation of a decimal number that is an offset into the string table. Executable images do not use a string table and do not support section names longer than 8 characters.

There are ways to find what a section is regardless of its name.

For .text sections they will require at least the `Execute` flag to be set.  And the virtual address of the .text section should be the same as the entry point which is defined in the optional header.

The import section (often named .idata) must have its address set in the second element of the array of directories that comes at the end of the optional header. Again looking at part of a dumpbin output:

```
    2 number of directories
    0 [       0] RVA [size] of Export Directory
 2000 [       0] RVA [size] of Import Directory
```

In this case the .idata section begins at virtual address 0x2000. Also, this section requires at least the `Read` flag.

A .data section may be more difficult to track down. Like the import section it must have at least the `Read` flag set but to be sure you could scan the .text section for opcodes which move data to or from an address. This address should be in one of the data sections and you can find the beginning of the section by looking at the section alignment in the optional header.
For example if you find `68 17 32 40 00` which translates to `PUSH 0x00403217` and the section alignment is 0x1000 then the start of the .data section may be 0x3000 (where 0x00400000 is the image base).